# Hindu God that uses hair as a weapon

Tags: shiva, vishnu, vedanta, advaita, bhakti

I went through deconstruction from evangelical Christianity about a year and a half ago. I studied every major religion and have landed on Advaita Vedanta.

When first studying Hinduism I had some interesting dreams... One of which has been stuck in my head for the past few months. It involved a blue Hindu God, pretty sure either Vishnu or Shiva, with growing hair that was used to cover up every other religious leader and symbol. From Buddha, Jesus, Mohammad, to yin and yang and beyond, all were coveted in this hair so as to say that the owner of the hair was superior to, and perhaps even the source of, these other gods.

The only thing about hair that I've been able to find is the story of the ganga River, and that isn't quite what I'm looking for.
There's also the story of Krishna and another god being incarnations of Vishnu's hair, which would be a lot closer to what I'm looking for, but that appears to be a mistranslation.

Any help would be great! As Advaita I'm not sure about bhakti yoga, but I'm certainly open to it.

Comment: Lord Shiva used his hair to create Veera Bhadra and Bhadra Kali who fought with Vishnu, This actually caused Pralaya or destruction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virabhadra

Comment: During Daksha Yagna episode, Lord Veerbhadra and Maa Rudra Kali came out of the 2 matted hairs of Bhagawan Shiva. Again, i think in Devi Puran, its there that from Lord Vishnu's 2 hairs (black and white) came Lord Krishna (from black hair) and Lord Balarama (from white hair).

Comment: ① Shaivites call Brahman Śiva and Vaishnavites call Brahman Viṣṇu. It is the same Brahman utilizing different stories as metaphor/symbolism b/c the ineffable cannot be accurately described through language. Understanding that all are One is essential to Advaita. ② The idea of superiority only makes sense from the perspective of māyā (illusion). If all are One, there can be no superiority. ③ As for symbolism, you can know by whether the hair was matted/tangled (Śiva) or not. ④ Properly Viṣṇu is black (like the ocean at night) & Śiva white (like camphor). Blue is used in modern renderings.

Answer (score 2):

> ***20-26.** **Rudra, the destroyer of the world, plucked out one matted hair.
> Then in anger he threw a slingshot at the top of the mountain.** O sage, the matted hair of the master was split in two by the touching. A great roar arose terrifying the great catastrophe. O celestial sage, **from the first half of that matted hair, rose up the powerful Vīrabhadra, the terrific leader of the Gaṇas.** He. stood lofty with two thousand hands blazing like the consuming fire. He enveloped the world all round and towered over it ten inches more. From the furious breath of Śiva, the great Rudra, hundred fevers and thirteen humours came out. **From the other half of the matted hair Mahākālī was born.** O dear one, she was very terrible and was surrounded by crores of goblins. The ruthless fevers had embodied forms. They were capable of terrifying the world. They were blazing with their fiery splendour. **(Shri Shiva Maha Puranam 2.2-2-20-26)***

> ***50-51.** When Brahmā and the other Devas went to Viṣṇu and prayed to Him then **Hari gave to Brahmā one hair of a black colour and one hair of a white colour. The Bhagavān Śrī Kṛṣṇa was born of that black hair and Śaṅkarṣaṇa Baladeva was born of the white hair.** They were both the incarnations of Viṣṇu. **(Srimad Devi Bhagwatam Maha Puranam 4.22.50-51).***

I hope this clarifies your queries.